What to include in fact and dimension table from election database
I am working with election dataset of India of year 2014

and data for 2019

I also have table for party names and descriptions


and finally state name with code.


I am not getting how do i create a data model with facts and dimension table.

Hi @SugamSharma, welcome to the site. What do you mean by "facts and dimension table"?

You relational database has different tables, each table are linked with eachother by foreign key, so you have tables with metadata called dimension table and you have table about the things you measured stored in fact table
